# Many-to-many relation on laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I have a question about many-to-many relations in laravel 5.5

I have these tables named `ads`, `attributes`, `categories`, `ads_attributes`
`categories` is one-to-many related to `ads`, so is `attributes`

and `ads` and `attributes` are many-to-many related in `ads_attributes`

The problem is: the primary keys in `attributes` are `['name', 'category_id']` (I know it's stupid but that's what is implemented atm and I'm not gonna restructure my tables)

So in `ads_attributes` I have these columns: `['attribute_name', 'category_id', 'ad_id']`

Laravel `belongsToMany()` method gives me this:

```
select `attributes`.*, `ads_attributes`.`ad_id` as `pivot_ad_id`, `ads_attributes`.`attribute_name` as `pivot_attribute_name`, `ads_attributes`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `attributes` inner join `ads_attributes` on `attributes`.`name` = `ads_attributes`.`attribute_name` where `ads_attributes`.`ad_id` in ('11')
```

while I need something like:

```
select `attributes`.*, `ads_attributes`.`ad_id` as `pivot_ad_id`, `ads_attributes`.`attribute_name` as `pivot_attribute_name`, `ads_attributes`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `attributes` inner join `ads_attributes` on `attributes`.`name` = `ads_attributes`.`attribute_name` and `attributes`.`category_id` = `ads_attributes`.`category_id` where `ads_attributes`.`ad_id` in ('11')
```

Any idea?

P.s sorry about my bad English, it's not my mother tongue

Comment: two primary key for one table ? is it possible ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi yes it is possible - however Idk how to tell laravel I have two primary keys in that table

Comment: I don't think so, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: @MahdiYounesi they've not predicted it but in mysql you can define a pair of columns as primary key